# What is the end of life for Loki?

Tags: release-loki, updates, elementary-project

I just installed Loki a couple of days ago, and I'd just like to know when support for it ends. I assume that since its base is Ubuntu 16.04, security support ends in 2021. Is that correct? And what about regular software updates from the elementary team, until when will that be given?

By the way, it's a pleasure working on elementary. :)

Answer (score 0):

The elementary team typically [only supports the latest release](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/22rhi3/how_long_is_luna_supported_for/) with feature updates, which I think is mainly a volunteer issue than anything else. The team tends to not set firm release dates and follows a "done when it's done" mentality. So now that Loki is released, there isn't a set date for Freya's end-of-life, but Freya-specific issues will likely not garner much attention. You can track the progress on the next release, Juno, [here](https://launchpad.net/elementary/+milestone/juno-beta1). That will likely be as close as it gets to Loki's end-of-life.

The OS is built atop Ubuntu "Long Term Support" releases, which also stop receiving feature support after about nine months but do receive major security fixes for five years ([April 2021](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Table_of_versions)). The team pushes those security updates to former releases and will post in a public place if for some reason an older release cannot update (users would be expected to upgrade for security reasons at that time).